# Compare a field in mysql query

Tags: mysql

How can I use the `if` statement in MYSQL query to return `yes` if it's true and `no` if it's not?

See the example :

`IF(table_name.field_name_value = 1, 'yes','no') AS active`

I'm trying something like this but with no success

Comment: What do you mean by " _with no success_ "? You wanted to say that " _this is not working_ "?

Comment: Tell us how it works and what is the expected result, if you want your problem to be solved for you, please.

Comment: @Tadeck, when i print active it doesn't show anything

Comment: @Tadeck,print_r($array['active']);

Comment: Your problem may be more complex and may not be related to this expression. The query works - see my updated answer.

Comment: Give use 1) **exact code** used for reading result from your query into `$array` variable, 2) information about **all the errors** encountered, 3) the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on `IF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
mysql> SELECT IF(1<2,'yes','no');
        -> 'yes'
```

So, basically, the syntax is as mentioned above.

**EDIT:**

You are saying my example is incorrect. Thus, I provide you a proof (which proves the example from the documentation I mentioned above):

I have a table, which has `uid` column, containing ID of the user. The table is part of the database on some site (which is not relevant). When I make the following query:

```
SELECT `uid`, IF(`uid`=3, 'yes', 'no') AS `active` FROM `mysite_users`;
```

I receive the following result:

```
+-----+--------+
| uid | active |
+-----+--------+
|   0 | no     |
|   1 | no     |
|   3 | yes    |
|   8 | no     |
|   9 | no     |
|  10 | no     |
|  11 | no     |
|  12 | no     |
|  13 | no     |
|  14 | no     |
|  15 | no     |
+-----+--------+
11 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Which is **exactly what I would expect (and what should be expected after reading the documentation)**. Is it still not working for you?

Comment: i'm trying to compare a field value with a static number, as i said above. my example is not correct so yours either!

Comment: @Revo: It is not my example, it is an **example from the documentation** (see page linked within my answer), so how could it be incorrect? Have you even checked it?

Comment: the problem is using **AS** !

Comment: @Revo: See the updated answer. **This is certainly working** - I have tested it twice and it works exactly at the documentation says.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` function:

```
select case
   when table_name.field_name_value = 1 then 'yes'
   else 'no'
   end case as active
  from table_name
```

Although `if` function should also work. Can you post your full query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE in mysql query for that.
Like

```
CASE WHEN table_name.field_name_valud = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END As active
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN table_name.field_name_value = 1 THEN 'yes'
   ELSE 'no' END;
```